# Unexpected Non-Laziness

Tags: lazy-evaluation, raku, rakudo

I wrote this code for this weeks [challenge](https://theweeklychallenge.org/blog/perl-weekly-challenge-123/) to produce ugly numbers.

```
sub factors( $n ) {
  if $n > 1 {
     $_, |factors $n div $_
      given ( grep $n %% *, 2..* ).first } }

.say for ( 1, |grep *.&factors.all ∈ ( 2, 3, 5 ), 2..* )[^150];
```

This works, in the sense it produces the correct ouput, but it does not behave lazily: The output does not start right away but 30 seconds after the start.

However when I remove the indexing and iterate over the bare sequence

```
.say for 1, |grep *.&factors.all ∈ ( 2, 3, 5 ), 2..*;
```

I get output immedeatly as expected.

This is a bug, yes?

Comment: a related point arose in a recent blog gfldex.wordpress.com/2021/08/02/only-infinite-elements from gfldex ... with [^∞] as the reifier

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a bug (though could possibly be documented better).  Indexing with `[]` reifies the elements it indexes over, so `[^150]` computes a (non-lazy) list of the first 150 elements.  (The rest of the list remains lazy, but those initial elements do not).

If you want to iterate lazily, you can use `&head` instead, which would give you the following final line:

```
.say for ( 1, |grep *.&factors.all ∈ ( 2, 3, 5 ), 2..* ).head(150);
```